# WiFi connecting problem in 5GHz networks

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

I have a 2017 13” MacBook Pro Retina, model A1407,  which doesn't even show my 5GHz WiFi connection. I tried so may times but failed. Other devices at home is working just fine with 5GHz network on WiFi,  But my MacBook Pro doesn't.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you connect to other (2.4GHz) networks?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure... Is *visibility* for 5G Wi-Fi network turned on? I.e., network is visible in the list of available networks, when you want to connect from any other device?

Also, try this:

1. Turn WPA2 only in the router settings..
2. Remove saved 5G Wi-Fi network on MBP and register again.

Just in case, make sure your MacBook supports 5G connectivity by:

1. Go to Apple menu (click  icon in the top left corner (menu bar))
2. Open `About This Mac`
3. Click `System Report` button
4. Go to `Network -> Wi-Fi` section, find `Supported PHY Modes` and make sure that your adapter at a minimum supports 802.11g/n.

[image]

And finally, [this](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/fix-wifi-problems-3605043/) article may be very useful for running diagnostics on Wi-Fi connections.

Hope this helps at least find the path to fix.

Comment: This answer is problematic.  1)  OP says he cannot see the network.  2) What is the network *visibility* setting? 3) What does WPA have to do *seeing* a network.  WPA/WPA2 is an authentication mechanism.  4) What does a saved network have to do with seeing the network?  5)  The 2017 MBP came with 802.11ac.  What leads you to believe that his MBP doesn't support this standard?  Finally 6) What in your link is applicable to this question? The fact that they say *Check your broadband provider* is clear they have no idea what they're talking about - you shouldn't put stock in this as a reference.

Comment: *visibility* means that network is set to broadcast its SSID. You are asking correct questions, @Allan, but without knowing the environment and all the nuances of OP using MBP, we can only guess. What if all other devices that OP states can see and use 5G were connected by some other person who knew hidden SSID for 5G? What if MBP adapter is not standard one? Correct diagnostic sometimes means excluding wrong versions too... Thanks for feedback though.

Comment: So, for "visibility" you mean whether the SSID is set to broadcast or not *on the router.*  Since there's no term called "visibility" you might want to clarify.  Secondly,  *...we can only guess.*  We don't guess.  We ask clarifying questions in comments.  You have a bunch of suppositions there which again, should be clarified in comments.  The premise that somehow the user *downgraded* their Airport card is...interesting, to say the least given that the last MBP to use 802.11n was back in 2013.  

Comment: Thank you for your powerful comments! I learnt a lot from them today.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of different things that can be the reason but I suggest you simply

1. Open System Preferences and make sure Show Wifi status in menu bar
   is selected..
2. Then while pressing the option key, click on the wifi icon in the menu bar.
3. Select Open wireless diagnostics.

Follow the on screen instructions and you should get your answer there without
    guess work on either side.

[image]

Comment: WiFi status doesn't mean much (as in nothing at all) when you can't see, much less get connected.  I also don't know what "guess work" you're alluding to.  To solve this, we need to do some bonafide *diagnostics*

Comment: Pretty rude of you for being a new comer and asking for help. Just because you can't see something doesn't mean it diagnosed the same by the machine you are trying to connect it with. As for the, guess work, that it just as it means... it's like saying I have a cough and  my eyes are blurry, so I can barely see... Who has the answer I need? smh. Just for the sake of amusement, did you even run it?

Comment: None of it's meant to be rude, but point out that guessing rarely works and here it usually gets down votes.  Now using your medical analogy, should I admit you to the (lung) cancer ward, get you a flu shot or call the fire department?  I'm betting you'd want someone who took the time to understand the problem before they recommended a cure.  As for running the app...I have countless times.  The question is...did you?  I ask because I know you can't have a status when you're not connected to anything and the problem is the OP can't see the network much less connect to it.

Comment: Well lets think that through, if you cant to the 5g it means most likely you are connecting to the 2g and most likely you are trying to connect to the 5g and first in order so therefore you actually do have a status and possibly an error. But thats my point made by you that you have tried something and have people guessing what you have tried or not and whats the fix when all we can do is guess based on your lack of info and apparently knowledge, Heres a clue why not call your provider that you give money to and let you both entertain each other ;)

Comment: You're assuming 1) there's a 2.4 **GHz** network *and* he's connecting to it.  2) If you successfully connect to the 2.4GHz network, what exactly would a status tell you about the 5GHz?  You see, there's guessing and then there's knowing and I what I do know is that I'd ***never*** contact any provider because they don't even know enough to guess.